# How can I optimise this Bubble Sort algorithm in MATLAB, or replace it by some other more efficient method?

Tags: matlab, octave

I would like to know how I could optimise this Bubble Sort algorithm that I made in a portion of MATLAB code, or replace it by some other more efficient method like QuickSort, TimSort or Merge Sort
In this case, Bubble Sort was used due to the fact that when the elements in the array to be ordered are swapped, the positions of the elements in another vector called categoria must also be swapped
Thank you

```
% Boolean variable (flag) to enter and exit the while loop
sigueBucle= true;
% The categories and the distance between each point are sorted
[~, N]= size(dataBase);
while (sigueBucle == true)
    sigueBucle= false;
    % Bubble sort algorithm (sinking sort)
    for i = 2 : N
        if (diferencias(i-1) > diferencias(i))
            % Swap the place of the elements of the array categoria
            auxiliar_etiqueta= categoria(i);
            categoria(i)= categoria(i-1);
            categoria(i-1)= auxiliar_etiqueta;
            % Swap the place of the elements of the distance array
            auxiliar_distanc= diferencias(i);
            diferencias(i)= diferencias(i-1);
            diferencias(i-1)= auxiliar_distanc;
            % Change sigueBucle to T (true) to re-enter the loop
            sigueBucle= true;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: MATLAB has a built-in function `sort` that you should use. Look up the documentation to learn how to reorder a second array in the same way.

Comment: Also, in MATLAB you can swap two values in an array as follows: `a([i,j]) = a([j,i])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [standard `sort` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html), and capture its second output "`ix`" to get an index vector that will allow you to re-order other arrays correspondingly.

```matlab
x = % ... some data ...
y = % ... another vector that needs to be kept ordered like x
[x,ix] = sort(x);  % Sort x
y = y(ix); % Apply the same re-ordering to y
```